# Cannot build ARToolKit nftSimple into android phone with Android ndk issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, augmented-reality, artoolkit

Hi I'm new to Android Studio and also ARToolKit, I'm trying to install and run an app from ARToolKit to my android phone.

I have imported ntfsimple into Android Studio, the nftSimple was provided while downloading ARtoolKit

while I've connected my device to my laptop and try to debug it, it shows error as below.

> Error:(23) *** Android NDK: Missing LOCAL_MODULE before including
>   BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY in
>   C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\NFT1\nftSimple\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk
>   .  Stop.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':nftSimple:compileDebugNdk'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 2

this is my android.mk

```
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)

# Pull ARToolKit into the build
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
ARTOOLKIT_DIR := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/../../../android
ARTOOLKIT_LIBDIR := $(call host-path, $(ARTOOLKIT_DIR)/obj/local/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
define add_artoolkit_module
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE:=$1
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=lib$1.a
    include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endef
ARTOOLKIT_LIBS := ar2 kpm util eden argsub_es armulti ar aricp jpeg arvideo
LOCAL_PATH := $(ARTOOLKIT_LIBDIR)
$(foreach module,$(ARTOOLKIT_LIBS),$(eval $(call add_artoolkit_module,$(module))))
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)

# Android arvideo depends on CURL.
CURL_DIR := $(ARTOOLKIT_DIR)/jni/curl
CURL_LIBDIR := $(call host-path, $(CURL_DIR)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))
define add_curl_module
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_MODULE:=$1
    #LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=lib$1.so
    #include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:=lib$1.a
    include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
endef
#CURL_LIBS := curl ssl crypto
CURL_LIBS := curl
LOCAL_PATH := $(CURL_LIBDIR)
$(foreach module,$(CURL_LIBS),$(eval $(call add_curl_module,$(module))))
LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# ARToolKit libs use lots of floating point, so don't compile in thumb mode.
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

LOCAL_PATH := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_MODULE := nftSimpleNative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nftSimple.cpp ARMarkerNFT.c trackingSub.c

# Make sure DEBUG is defined for debug builds. (NDK already defines NDEBUG for release builds.)
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
endif

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(ARTOOLKIT_DIR)/../include/android $(ARTOOLKIT_DIR)/../include
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lGLESv1_CM -lz
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ar
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ar2 kpm util eden argsub_es armulti aricp cpufeatures jpeg arvideo
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += $(CURL_LIBS)
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += $(CURL_LIBS)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)
```

this is my build-shared-libraru.mk

```
LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT := BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY
LOCAL_MAKEFILE     := $(local-makefile)

$(call check-defined-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT))
$(call check-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE))
$(call check-LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)

# we are building target objects
my := TARGET_

$(call handle-module-filename,lib,$(TARGET_SONAME_EXTENSION))
$(call handle-module-built)

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARY
include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-module.mk
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the documentation:
http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_native

closely. This shows you how to setup your development environment and what you need to build and how to build it.

Let me know if you get stuck.

---

Edit:

From your comment I understand that you are using Windows.

Keep in mind, on Windows you need to install GitBash. Git itself it not enough!
[image]
Git Bash can be installed as part of the Git installer. So please rerun the installer if you did not install Git Bash.

The other precondition is that you have set all of the following ANDROID_* and the NDK environment variables:
[image]

On Git Bash navigate to your ARToolKit root/android directory:
<>/android

In this directory you will find a build.sh script. Run that script in Git Bash with the following command:

```
./build.sh
```

The build of the native libraries starts. After that you can run build_native_examples.sh if you are interested in the native examples as well.

Comment: Sorry I'm really really new to this and I'm having a hard time to understand it. I have all the prerequisites settled. Can I know what is the Git installation for?

Comment: When you are on Windows the build.sh won't work within a Windows command line as it uses functions not know to the Windows command line. That is why we recommend installing GIT with the GIT bash to be able to run build.sh.

Comment: Thanks! I got Git for my Windows already and next how do I start building the native android library?

Comment: but I'm having 'permission denied' while entering <>/android

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are entering? Where is your ARToolKit home directory?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

I think it is not pointing to the path where jni folder is loacted, so it cannot identify .mk file which is inside jni folder
ARTOOLKIT_DIR := $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/../../../android
In this section you give the path where jni folder is located.
ARTOOLKIT_DIR:=~/AndroidStudioProjects/extractedZipFolderName/android